# Show static block only on catalogsearch page

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, catalogsearch

I want to show a static block only on the catalogsearch page. My catalogsearch page is the same layout as 2columns-left.phtml. I don't really want to make another layout for the catalogsearch. Is there a way that i can show the static block only on the catalogsearch page ?

Comment: Did you checked catalogsearch.xml?

Comment: Yes, but how can i set the place the banner will show up there. I want it to show up below the header but above the content of the search...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code in **2columns-left.phtml.phtml** after

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
```

this with your block identifier:

```
<?php 
     $route=$this->getRequest()->getRouteName();
     $controller=$this->getRequest()->getControllerName();
     $action=$this->getRequest()->getActionName();
    if($route=='catalogsearch' && $controller=="result" &&   $action=='index'){
       $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml() ;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, i found the file. The problem now is that it shows in the content side of the 2columns-left. So the banner is not 100%, because it is in: colmain. I need to have it cover the leftbar and col main, so it should be above those 2.

Comment: check modified answer

Comment: Thank you very much, had to add 'echo' before the static block code, but after that it worked like a charm!